# Como passar um plugin Jquery como parâmetro para o evento On

Tags: jquery

Eu utilizo o plugin Datatables, e na tabela haverá a opção de editar e excluir, eu quero mostrar uma confirmação caso o usuário clique em excluir. Por isso, utilizarei o plugin "confirm", entretanto, esse plugin só é válido para a primeira página do DataTable, nas outras páginas ou quando faço uma pesquisa ele não funciona.
Pensei no evento "on", mas como faço para passar o plugin "confirm" invés da função (3º parâmetro).

Algo como:

```
$("html").on("click", ".confirm", $.confirm());
```

Comment: Podes testar sem invocar a função... `$("html").on("click", ".confirm", $.confirm);`. Se não funcionar indica por favor que plugin é esse e onde está a documentação e código fonte para podermos perceber melhor o plugin e o problema.

Comment: Não posso invocar sem os parâmetros, por os utilizo (passando a mensagem, os botões, etc)... O plugin em questão é o seguinte:  http://myclabs.github.io/jquery.confirm/

Comment: já tentou $("html").on("click", ".confirm", function(){ $(this).confirm() }); ?

Comment: Já havia tentado dessa forma, assim só funciona no segunda clique :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode passar uma função que chame o `$.confirm`. Por exemplo:

```
$("#elemento").on("click", function() {
    $.confirm();
});
```

Comment: Quando vi seu comentário pensei: "É isso!"... Mas, ao executar o código, também não funcionou... Mesmo problema, funciona na primeira página, mas na segunda não funciona :(

Comment: Valeu, só faltou um parâmetro na sua resposta... Assim funcionou: $("html").on("click", ".confirm", function(){
 $.confirm() });